# PCL dependencies on ROS electric

Tags: pcl, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was following a [tutorial](http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/passthrough.php#passthrough)  on PCL. It seems that I have a lot of functionalities that cannot be used. There are also some warnings on the header files. The header files that got warning are:

- pcl/point_types.h
- pcl/filters/passthrough.h
- sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h
- pcl/ros/conversions.h
- pcl/point_cloud.h

Do I need to explicitly add/install extra packages like pcl_filter? I have also been trying to install in on my "ROS electric" but it seems that it is not compatible with it. The pcl_filter that I used is from [this](http://brown-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/experimental/pcl_filter/).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11607/pcl-dependencies-on-ros-electric/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-10-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The standalone PCL library is not compatible with ROS electric. This problem will be resolved in some future release.

To run PCL with ROS, install the [perception_pcl](http://www.ros.org/wiki/perception_pcl) stack, and perhaps [perception_pcl_addons](http://www.ros.org/wiki/perception_pcl_addons).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-10-20**:
It seems to work but I did not manage to install perception_pcl_addons, but I guess that one is optional.